# showing verticies in openGL

Tags: c, linux, opengl

I have a program that renders a 3D wire mesh model using this code fragment in a loop.

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3d(xs,ys,zs);
glVertex3d(xe,ye,ze);
glEnd();
```

I need to add functionality so that the vertices where the line starts and ends can be rendered if the user desires, probably using a small shaded circle. The circle should be of a constant screen size, probably 4-6 pixels across and rendered at a size that is independent of where the camera is, or how close it is.

Can anyone suggest how to render such a vertex?

Comment: Did you try to use GL_POINTS and GLPointSize(size) ?

Comment: thanks. I'd missed 'glPointSize'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GL_POINTS` in your `glBegin` together with `glPointSize` function.